# Are puzzle preservation questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

I don't know how this would work with puzzle types outside of jigsaws or puzzle boxes, but is it okay to ask about the best way to preserve a puzzle? I assume I would need to be specific... for example that this:

> How do I preserve a 3D jigsaw made of plastic?

is better than this:

> How do I preserve a 3D puzzle?

But I'm wondering if the question itself is okay. When I was going to ask this initially, the title box had the "What is your creation and solving of puzzles question" text in there and I was skeptical about asking since my question has nothing to do with creation OR solving a puzzle.

Comment: I don't see how it would be on-topic at any other SE...

Comment: I don't think I would personally consider this on-topic, but I'm having trouble formulating a specific reason why.

Comment: That sentence in the title box is an unfortunate consequence of a technical feature. [We have a request to change it to just “your puzzling question”](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23/the-default-text-for-the-ask-question-title-box).

Answer (score 2):

My inclination is that until we have a Puzzl *es* site, instead of a Puzzl *ing* site (which will very likely never happen), I'd think that questions related to physical puzzle care/preservation/etc.  I don't anticipating them happening often enough to be an issue, but this isn't really a bad fit - people here would be likely to know.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that technically it is off-topic because it's less about the puzzles themselves and more about the physical medium for the puzzles, but I can't see it being off-topic enough that it would belong elsewhere.